# Click the URL on Google Chat → I want to start Firefox

Tags: google-hangouts

I use Google Chat.

After clicking the URL on Google Chat, I want to use another web browser instead of Google Chrome.
How do I use a different web browser instead of Google Chrome?

- Click the URL on Google Chat → I want to start Firefox.
- Click the URL on Google Chat → I don't want to start Google Chrome.

that's all.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This question better suits another group tom y opinion. https://superuser.com/search?q=google+hangouts-chat